# can I use a variable to extract a substring in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I need to extract the characters of a string one by one in a loop. Ideally, I would've done something like this, but as you might have guessed, it doesn't work.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a len=5
set var=abcde
for /l %%n in (1,1,%len%) do (
    set /a num=%%n - 1
    echo %var:~!num!,1%
)
```

it works seamlessly if I replace `!num!` with a plain number, but with the variable, behaves as if the percent signs aren't there and echoes:

```
var:~0,1
var:~1,1
var:~2,1
var:~3,1
var:~4,1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To directly fix your issue replace:

```
echo %var:~!num!,1%
```

with:

```
call echo %%var:~!num!,1%%`
```

But you can do it without `set /a num=%%n - 1` because you are already counting using `for /L` but note we are counting from 0.

```
Also note, we start couting from 0.
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a len=4
set "var=abcde"
for /l %%n in (0,1,%len%) do (
    echo(!var:~%%n,1!
)
```

Comment: your example code works perfectly fine for echoing, but I'd like to write it to a variable. echoing it was mainly for troubleshooting. My bad, I should've said that in the question.

Comment: I got it to work with a little bit of tweaking. Thanks for the help

Comment: Well, show you want to write it and I can show you how.